# Stacked bar chart with line percent highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts, graphics

How can I achieve this graph in Highcharts?

Graph design : https://i.stack.imgur.com/8G7DE.png

Help please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve it in many ways. You can start from this demo: https://www.highcharts.com/demo/combo, next you need to add some logic to show the percentage line in the second axis. To show the table under use: https://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-parsed